Discrepancies between the Install Date and Created Date in the License Management App (LMA)
Why is the Install Date different from the Created Date?
In this Trailhead module, it states:
https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/appexchange_licensing/appexchange_licensing_manage
Whenever a prospect installs your package, the LMA creates two records in the org where the LMA is installed:
A Lead record that identifies the prospect
A License record for that prospect, based on the licensing terms for your package
According to the Trailhead module, the License record is created when a prospect installs a package. So, the Install Date and Created Date should be the same, right? Could you please let me know if I am missing something here?

Hi and welcome to SFSE. Please [edit] your question to state are you seeing and whether the prospect has only installed the package once, whether they have done an upgrade etc.
